# How to check if sum of list elements are equal to the last element in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, sum, modulo

Input is a list with 9 elements. 
    
I would like to check if the first 8 elements's sum/10's remainder (with the algorithm below, taj's second line) is equal to the last (9th) element.

At the moment my program counts the remainder but i can't figure out how to check it. I have tried several ways.

```
oddS :: Int-> Int
oddS x = x*3

evenS :: Int -> Int
evenS y = y*7


taj :: [Int] -> Int
taj (a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h:w) = (oddS a + evenS b + oddS c + evenS d + oddS e + evenS f + oddS g + evenS h) `mod` 10
```

I know it is not the best solution but it does the job.

An alternative solution with the help of  Willem.

```
  check :: [Int] -> Bool
  check xs = xn == taj xs
      where xn = last xs
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `oddS` and `evenS`? I don't see why you multiply with `3` and `7` if you want to calculate the sum?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  it's a validation algorithm. It works like that. 
The input list is valid if the first 8 elements's  (the sum of odd indexed elements*3 and even indexed elements*7)   mod 10 equals to the last element.

Comment: @Georg321: and where is that stated in the question?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you are right, i thought it is obvious if you see evenS and oddS, sorry my fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to check if the first 8 elements's sum/10's remainder is equal to the last (9th) element.
>
> it's a validation algorithm. It works like that. The input list is valid if the first 8 elements's (the sum of odd indexed elements*3 and even indexed elements*7) mod 10 equals to the last element. - comment

You can also use *recursion* to check the condition by using an *accumulator* (or perhaps two to check the length) that accumulates the *running sum* and checks it when it reaches the last element. So something like:

```
check9 :: [Int] -> Bool
check9 = check9' 8 0
    where check9' n s [xn] = n == 0 && s `mod` 10 == xn
          check9' n s (x:x2:xs) = check9' (n-2) (s+3*x+7*x2) xs
          check9' _ _ _ = False
```

A more elegant way to solve this however is using builtins like `sum :: Num a => [a] -> a`, `zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]`, `cycle :: [a] -> [a]` and `splitAt :: [a] -> a`:

```
-- alternative version

check9 :: [Int] -> Bool
check9 xs | (xi,[xn]) <- splitAt 8 xs = xn == mod (sum (zipWith (*) xi $ cycle [3,7])) 10
          | otherwise = False
```

Comment: It's clear but my problem is i don't know how to check if (oddS a + evenS b + oddS c + evenS d + oddS e + evenS f + oddS g + evenS h) `mod` 10) equals to the last element. That's what i don't understand honestly. As i tried to explain you above.

Comment: @George312: I updated the answer, now it works with the `evenS`/`oddS` sequence.

Comment: i really appreciate your help but somehow it gives false for a valid input (0,2,3,1,5,8,3,0,0). I just don't understand why.

Comment: I found a valid solution with your help. Thanks

Comment: @George312: I found the mistake, it should be `n-2` instead of `n-1`.

Comment: Yes it is working now but i could figure out my own solution with you help. Thanks a lot mate.